# How to resize text added with fillText() in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have three canvas-elements that lay over the another. the first is a picture the second a filter and the third should be a text. I made the filter resizeable und draggable with the mouse events, but somehow this does not work with the text the same way. and i want to resize the text with four corner buttons and want to make it draggable. The text is added via a self-programmed simple texteditor.

[click me please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r5cDF.png)

[click me please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oh3ae.png)

The red square is where the rectangles are drawn now, but htey should be around the text, and the blue square is the hitbox to drag the text.

Now my Js-Code for the text.

```js
var colorButton = document.getElementById("primary_color");
var textArea = document.getElementById("text");
var editor = document.getElementById("text");
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
var textFontFamily = document.getElementById("selectForFonts");
var textColor;
var fontStyleFamily = 'Arial';
var boldness = 'normal';
var italicness = 'normal';
var data;


/**Function to get the color and color the text*/
colorButton.onchange = function() {
  textColor = colorButton.value;
  textArea.style.color = textColor;
}

function showOverlay() {
  overlay.style.display = "block";
}

function writeText() {

  $(function() {

    var canvasText = document.getElementById("canvasText");
    var ctxText = canvasText.getContext("2d");
    var $canvasText = $("#canvasText");

    var canvasOffset;
    var offsetX;
    var offsetY;
    var isDown;

    var dx;
    var dy;
    var lastX = 0;
    var lastY = 0;

    var iW;
    var iH;
    var iLeft = 0;
    var iTop = 0;
    var iRight, iBottom, iOrientation;

    canvasText.height = renderableHeight;
    canvasText.width = renderableWidth;

    overlay.style.display = "none";
    data = textArea.value;
    canvasText.style.display = "block";
    canvasOffset = $canvasText.offset();

    offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
    offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
    isDown = false;

    var textWidthtemp = ctxText.measureText(data);
    var textWidth = textWidthtemp.width;
    var textHeight = parseInt("50");

    var font = italicness + " " + boldness + " " + textHeight + "px " + fontStyleFamily;

    iW = textWidth;
    iH = textHeight;



    facW = 1; // canvasText.width  / canvasText.offsetWidth;
    facH = 1; //canvasText.height / canvasText.offsetHeight;


    console.log(facW + " " + facH);

    iRight = iLeft + iW;
    iBottom = iTop + iH;

    console.log(iTop);
    console.log(iBottom);
    console.log(iRight);
    console.log(iBottom);

    iOrientation = "Wide"; //(iW >= iH) ? "Wide" : "Tall";

    draw(true);

    var border = 10;
    var isLeft = false;
    var isRight = false;
    var isTop = false;
    var isBottom = false;
    var iAnchor;

    canvasText.onmousedown = handleMousedown;
    canvasText.onmousemove = handleMousemove;
    canvasText.onmouseup = handleMouseup;
    canvasText.onmouseout = handleMouseup;


    function hitResizeAnchor(x, y) {

      // which borders are under the mouse
      isLeft = (x * facW > iLeft && x * facW < iLeft + border);
      isRight = (x * facW < iRight && x * facW > iRight - border);
      isTop = (y * facH > iTop && y * facH < iTop + border);
      isBottom = (y * facH < iBottom && y * facH > iBottom - border);
      isDragged = (x * facW > iLeft && x * facW < iRight && y * facH > iTop && y * facH < iBottom);

      // return the appropriate anchor
      if (isTop && isLeft) {
        return (iOrientation + "TL");
      }
      if (isTop && isRight) {
        return (iOrientation + "TR");
      }
      if (isBottom && isLeft) {
        return (iOrientation + "BL");
      }
      if (isBottom && isRight) {
        return (iOrientation + "BR");
      }
      if (isDragged) {
        return "DR"
      }
      return (null);
    }

    var resizeFunctions = {
      WideTR: function(x, y) {
        iRight = x * facW;
        iTop = iBottom - (iH * (iRight - iLeft) / iW);
      },

      TallTR: function(x, y) {
        iTop = y * facH;
        iRight = iLeft + (iW * (iBottom - iTop) / iH);
      },

      WideBR: function(x, y) {
        iRight = x * facW;
        iBottom = iTop + (iH * (iRight - iLeft) / iW);
      },

      TallBR: function(x, y) {
        iBottom = y * facH;
        iRight = iLeft + (iW * (iBottom - iTop) / iH);
      },

      WideBL: function(x, y) {
        iLeft = x * facW;
        iBottom = iTop + (iH * (iRight - iLeft) / iW);
      },

      TallBL: function(x, y) {
        iBottom = y * facH;
        iLeft = iRight - (iW * (iBottom - iTop) / iH);
      },

      WideTL: function(x, y) {
        iLeft = x * facW;
        iTop = iBottom - (iH * (iRight - iLeft) / iW);
      },

      TallTL: function(x, y) {
        iBottom = y * facH;
        iLeft = iRight - (iW * (iBottom - iTop) / iH);
      },

      DR: function(x, y) {
        console.log("DX: " + dx + "DY: " + dy);
        iLeft += dx;
        iRight += dx;
        iTop += dy;
        iBottom += dy;
      }
    };

    function handleMousedown(e) {
      // tell the browser we'll handle this mousedown
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      var mouseX = e.clientX - offsetX;
      var mouseY = e.clientY - offsetY;

      iAnchor = hitResizeAnchor(mouseX, mouseY);
      if (iAnchor == "DR") {
        lastX = mouseX;
        lastY = mouseY;

        isDown = (true);

      } else {
        isDown = (iAnchor);
      }
    }

    function handleMouseup(e) {
      // tell the browser we'll handle this mouseup
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();

      if (iAnchor == "DR") {
        isDown = false;
      } else {
        isDown = false;
        draw(true);
      }
    }

    function handleMousemove(e) {
      // tell the browser we'll handle this mousemove
      e.preventDefault();
      e.stopPropagation();
      // return if we're not dragging
      if (!isDown) {
        return;
      }

      // get MouseX/Y
      var mouseX = e.clientX - offsetX;
      var mouseY = e.clientY - offsetY;

      //if Picture is dragged
      if (iAnchor == "DR") {
        dx = mouseX - lastX;
        dy = mouseY - lastY;

        // set the lastXY for next time we're here
        lastX = mouseX;
        lastY = mouseY;

        resizeFunctions[iAnchor](mouseX, mouseY);
        draw(true);
      } else {
        // reset iLeft,iRight,iTop,iBottom based on drag
        resizeFunctions[iAnchor](mouseX, mouseY);

        // redraw the resized image
        draw(false);
      }
    }


    function draw(withAnchors) {
      ctxText.clearRect(0, 0, canvasText.width, canvasText.height);
      ctxText.font = font;
      ctxText.fillStyle = textColor;
      ctxText.fillText(data, iLeft, iTop - textHeight);
      if (withAnchors) {
        ctxText.fillRect(iLeft, iTop - textHeight, border, border);
        ctxText.fillRect(iRight - border, iTop - textHeight, border, border);
        ctxText.fillRect(iRight - border, iBottom - border - textHeight, border, border);
        ctxText.fillRect(iLeft, iBottom - border - textHeight, border, border);
      }
    }
  });
}

function bold() {
  var temp = textArea.style.fontWeight;

  if (temp == 'normal') {
    textArea.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
    boldness = 'bold';
  } else {
    textArea.style.fontWeight = 'normal';
    boldness = 'normal';
  }

}

function italic() {
  var temp = textArea.style.fontStyle;

  if (temp == 'normal') {
    textArea.style.fontStyle = 'italic';
    italicness = 'italic';
  } else {
    textArea.style.fontStyle = 'normal';
    italicness = 'normal';
  }

}

function changeFont() {
  var temp = textFontFamily.options[textFontFamily.selectedIndex].value;
  console.log(temp);

  textArea.style.fontFamily = temp;
  fontStyleFamily = temp;
}
```

```html
<div id="display" class="flex-workspace-item-big z-depth-2">
  <canvas id=canvas style="width:inherit ;height:inherit; position: absolute; z-index: 0;"></canvas>
  <canvas id=canvasFilter style="width:inherit ;height:inherit; position: absolute; display: none; z-index: 1"></canvas>
  <canvas id=canvasText style="width:inherit ;height:inherit; position: absolute; display: none; z-index: 2"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.font`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/font) to change the font size

Comment: @jonatjano but that does not change the problem of the hitbox and the missplaced rectangles.

Comment: ok looking at your images I think I found something, the problem with canvas  text is that their position if positioned by their bottomleft corner while literally everthing else is positioned by their topleft corner. meaning you need to position text differently than the way you position others objects

Comment: Ok thanks i will take a look at it.